# Out of heap space with hibernate - what's the problem?

Tags: java, hibernate, out-of-memory

I'm running into the following (common) error after I added a new DB table, hibernate class, and other classes to access the hibernate class:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Here's the relevant code:

From .jsp:

```
<% 
com.companyconnector.model.HomepageBean homepage = new com.companyconnector.model.HomepageBean();
%>
```

From HomepageBean:

```
public class HomepageBean {

        ...

    private ReviewBean review1;
    private ReviewBean review2;
    private ReviewBean review3;



    public HomepageBean () {

        ...

        GetSurveyResults gsr = new GetSurveyResults();
        List<ReviewBean> rbs = gsr.getRecentReviews();  
        review1 = rbs.get(0);  
        review2 = rbs.get(1);
        review3 = rbs.get(2);
}
```

From GetSurveyResults:

```
public List<ReviewBean> getRecentReviews() {

    List<OpenResponse> ors = DatabaseBean.getRecentReviews();
    List<ReviewBean> rbs = new ArrayList<ReviewBean>();


    for(int x = 0; ors.size() > x; x =+ 2) {

     String employer = "";
     rbs.add(new ReviewBean(ors.get(x).getUid(), employer, ors.get(x).getResponse(), ors.get(x+1).getResponse()));

    }

    return rbs;

}
```

and lastly, from DatabaseBean:

```
public static List<OpenResponse> getRecentReviews() {

  SessionFactory session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
  Session sess = session.openSession();
  Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();

  List results = sess.createQuery( 
    "from OpenResponse where (uid = 46) or (uid = 50) or (uid = 51)"
  ).list();

  tx.commit();
  sess.flush();
  sess.close();
  return results;

}
```

Sorry for all the code and such a long message, but I'm getting over a million instances of ReviewBean (I used jProfiler to find this).  Am I doing something wrong in the for loop in GetSurveyResults?  Any other problems?

I'm happy to provide more code if necessary.

Thanks for the help.

Joe

Comment: show us the mapping/annotations...you are probably loading your entire db into memory.

Comment: Yes, your loop is incorrect. Start with a normal looking loop and work backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JProfiler to find which objects occupy the memory is a good first step. Now that you know that needlessly many instances are created, a logical next analysis step is to run your application in debug mode, and step through the code that allocates the ReviewBeans. If you do that, the bug should be obvious. (I am pretty sure I spotted it, but I'd rather teach you how to find such bugs on your own. It's a skill that is indispensable for any good programmer).

Comment: I always found debugging Hibernate weirdness is substantially harder than your run of the mill logical error, so I think it would be a good idea to mock all that stuff out first before starting your debug session.

Comment: ... or you can use "step over" or "run to line" (or "run" with breakpoints) to step over the calls to hibernate.

Comment: You are correct of course. In truth, I had been having flashbacks to my experiences profiling with TPTP, which, at the time, was causing Hibernate to run like a dog unless you specifically excluded all the Hibernate classes. For your typical debug, it ain't so bad as you point out.

Comment: Thanks.  Stupid mistake.  Should be "+=" instead of "=+".  Why was this not a compiler error though?

Comment: Because the compiler discards whitespace between tokens, it looks like `x = +2;` where `+` is the unary plus operator, a rarely used companion to the unary minus operator, as in `x = -1;`

Answer (score 0):

Also you probably want to close session/commit transaction if the finally block to make sure it's always invoked event if your method throws exception. Standard pattern for working with resources in java (simplified pseudo code):

```
Session s = null;
try {
 s = openSession();
 // do something useful
}
finally {
  if (s != null) s.close();
}
```